# kinect raw data

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ubuntu 11.10 and openni.

My question is how to convert the raw depth data to XYZ point?

(x,y,d) coordinate of (pixel, pixel, mm)

I want to know how to convert it to (mm, mm, mm)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37949/kinect-raw-data/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-07-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-04**:
Are you using the openni_camera stack? What launch file are you using to start the Kinect (e.g. openni_launch openni.launch)?

**Comment by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on 2012-07-04**:
I am using openni_launch openni.launch to start  the kinect.

**Comment by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on 2012-07-04**:
Can you also teach me the changing fomula??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi rosmaker,

If you are using

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

then the conversion is already being done for you.

You only need to subscribe to the topic */camera/depth_registered/points*. This topic is of type *sensor_msgs/PointCloud2* and represents the 3D point cloud of the scene in meters.

You can find further information on how to access point cloud data in http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on 2012-07-05**:
What is the way to use the scene in [mm]? If I am using other launch file or not, does I use other way?

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-07-05**:
Well, if you want your coordinates in mm, one thing you can do is multiply by 1000 all the values in /camera/depth_registered/points

**Comment by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on 2012-07-05**:
openni have convertprojectivetorealworld function in windows openni. Is this same the topic /camera/depth_registered/points?

**Comment by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on 2012-07-05**:
And does raw depth data send by the kinect on 11bit ? how about changed xyz data?

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-06-21**:
how do I do the opposite? How do I convert the pixels around point (0.1 meters, 0.52 meters to pixel (x, y) position? I am using the old Kinect (640 x 480 resulution kinect)